# What is 'Submitting a form from another website' called?

Tags: php, forms, submit

I saw an abbreviation for this once but I forgot it... It's really hard / nearly impossible to get relevant search results when I google 'Prevent form submit from other website'.

So, I would like to know what cross-domain form submission is called (I mean like 'officially') and the abbreviation.

Comment: Cross site request forgery?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. So hard to find when you don't know what it's called.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for `XSS attack` (cross-site scripting)?